# How do i remove PHP 7.0.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)

Tags: 12.04, php

```
PHP 7.0.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Mar 15 2017 09:49:51) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I tried a few different things but i can't seem to get it removed. I tried to purge:

```
# apt-get install ppa-purge
# ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
apt-get purge php7.*
```